# How can we Remove "New" Button from Custom Object Tab View?

Tags: custom-object, button

New ABC_CustomObject record should only be created through the VF page and not directly from the standard record page from the ABC_CustomObject Tab.

Comment: What is the reason for taking this approach? The more you diverge from how the Salesforce Platform works the more headaches you'll give yourself. For example, if the VF page adds special logic to set extra values in the new record on creation, what should happen when these records are bulk imported or created through some integration? You would be better off considering adding the special logic in a flow, process builder or trigger automation against the custom object and then use standard UI for creating these records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to remove/hide the "New" button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/is-it-possible-to-remove-hide-the-new-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite standard button behavers with VF page see article bellow.
So you can use your VF page when new is clicked.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_customize_override.htm&type=5

Or you can hide the button.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_detail_page_buttons.htm&type=5

But as Phil W mentioned, you should keep in mind that in the future there is a chance this will break something or at least forbit you from using advantages that come with standard SF functionalities.

Please share if this helped you or maybe provide more details for better answer.